# Why use uWSGI max-requests option?

Tags: uwsgi

I see many of the uWSGI configs posted here and the ones I came across for existing applications at work also have max-requests populated with values from 100's to 1000's.

What is the purpose of recycling your processes after a set number of requests? Are you trying to avoid memory leaks, forcing your application to handle resets gracefully?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, avoiding memory leak is one of the main reason of setting max request. There is also another parameter named harakiri which helps server get rid of bad application, locking the resources.

Comment: Any other alternative other than max requests to avoid memory leaks without a force restart?